# Programmatically create a predicate for ordering an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I want to create a generic extension method for the `IQueryable<T>` interface, which would take some string input and generate an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` output.

I have tried programmatically creating an `Expression<Func<T,TKey>>` but `TKey` can only be determined at runtime.

Here is the implementation I have come up with thus far

```cs
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> This, string sort) where T : class
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
            var (isDescending, normalizedSortParam) = NormalizeSortParam(sort);
            MemberExpression propertyExpression;
            try
            {
                propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, normalizedSortParam);
            }
            catch(ArgumentException)
            {
                propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
            }

            var outputType = propertyExpression.Type;
            var filterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, outputType>>(propertyExpression, param);
            return isDescending ? This.OrderByDescending(filterExpression) : This.OrderBy(filterExpression);
        }
```

For context, the `Id` field exists on all types T that the Sort method would be called on

This doesn't get successfully compiled (as expected) but I do not know how to specify the output type at runtime.

Comment: In the past, I’ve used another type constraint on T. E.g, where T : IIdentifiable, class. (The IIdentifiable interface having a property / get accessor for the id)

Comment: See [the overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda?view=netframework-4.8) for `Expression.Lambda` - some of them take the type as a runtime argument, instead of as generic type parameters. You'll probably have to invoke `OrderBy` through reflection as well, but you can then cast the result back to an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way to do this is to build expression with `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` method and create new queryable:

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sort) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var (isDescending, normalizedSortParam) = NormalizeSortParam(sort);
        MemberExpression propertyExpression;
        try
        {
            propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, normalizedSortParam);
        }
        catch(ArgumentException)
        {
            propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
        }

        Type outputType = propertyExpression.Type;
        LambdaExpression filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, param);

        // Call OrderBy or OrderByDescending on original query expression
        MethodCallExpression orderedExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            isDescending ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy",
            new []{ typeof(T), outputType },
            new [] { query.Expression, filterExpression }
        );

        // Create new query from orderedExpression 
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderedExpression);
    }
```